# Getting POST data from SELECT dropdown with variable value

Tags: php, dropdown, postdata

I need to create as many dropdowns as values from a database table query in worpress. I can't get post data to usermeta table from foreach dropdown list . This is the code:

```
$custom_posts_type = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT label,id FROM $table_name");
      foreach ($custom_posts_type as $custom_post_type) {
           $custom_post_type_name = $custom_post_type->label;
           $custom_post_type_id = $custom_post_type->id;
           ?>
           <p>   
           <label for="dropdown">Permisos de usuario para <?php echo $custom_post_type_name;?>: </label>
           <?php                                               
           $user_custom_post = 'user_custom_' . $custom_post_type_name;
           $selected = get_the_author_meta( $user_custom_post, $user->ID ); 
           $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($custom_post_type_name);                        
           $label = $post_type_object->label;
           $posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=> $custom_post_type_name, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'suppress_filters' => false, 'posts_per_page'=>-1));                        
           echo '<select name="' . $user_custom_post . '" id="' . $user_custom_post . '">';                                               
            ?>
            <option value="all" <?php selected( $user_custom_post[0], "all" ); ?>>All <?php echo $label;?></option>
            <?php 
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                echo '<option value="', $post->ID, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>';
             }?>            
           <?php
           echo '</select>';
           ?>                        
           </p>
          <?php
          update_user_meta( $user->ID, $user_custom_post, $_POST[$user_custom_post] );                        
 } //endforeach
```

I appreciate your help.
Thks

Comment: can you post what your generated html looks like, and what you get if you "var_dump" the $_GET or $_POST variable (depending on what method attribute you are using in your form)

Comment: Thks for your comment flynorc.  "Notice: Undefined index: user_custom_xxxxxxx"  and database save:  "null"

Comment: you should have 2 files (or 2 parts of code in one file)... one part that generates the <form> element with method and action attributes. and that form then contains your <select> elements with the <options>.
and the second part is where you retreive the values submitted with the form and process that information (store to db or whatever it is you are doing)

Answer (score 0):

Probably... I have created two functions without foreach. And, if I don't use variables it works:

```
 add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'pglr_user_pages' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'pglr_user_pages' );
    add_action( 'user_register', 'pglr_user_pages' );

    function pglr_user_pages( $user ) { 
            $post_type = "page"; ?>
            <p>   
                <label for="dropdown">Asignar <?php echo $post_type;?>: </label>
                <?php 
                $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_page', $user->ID ); 
                $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                $label = $post_type_object->label;
                $posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=> $post_type, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'suppress_filters' => false, 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
                echo '<select name="user_custom_page_value" id="user_custom_page_value">';            
                ?>                    
                <option value="all" <?php selected( '', "all" ); ?>>All <?php echo $label;?></option>
                <?php
                foreach ($posts as $post) {
                    echo '<option value="', $post->ID, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>';
                }?>            
                <?php
                echo '</select>';                
                ?>                      
            </p>       
        <?php     
        } 


    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_pglr_user_pages' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_pglr_user_pages' );

    function save_pglr_user_pages( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    //save dropdown
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_custom_page', $_POST['user_custom_page_value'] );
    }
```

However, this code doesn't work:

```
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'pglr_user_pages' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'pglr_user_pages' );
    add_action( 'user_register', 'pglr_user_pages' );

    function pglr_user_pages( $user ) { 
           $post_type = "page"; ?>
            <p>   
                <label for="dropdown">Asignar <?php echo $post_type;?>: </label>
                <?php 
                **global $user_custom_post;**
                **$user_custom_post = 'user_custom_' . $post_type;**                                      
                $selected = get_the_author_meta( **$user_custom_post**, $user->ID ); 
                $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
                $label = $post_type_object->label;
                $posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=> $post_type, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'suppress_filters' => false, 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
                echo '<select name="user_custom_page_value" id="user_custom_page_value">';            
                ?>
                <option value="all" <?php selected( '', "all" ); ?>>All <?php echo $label;?></option>
                <?php
                foreach ($posts as $post) {
                    echo '<option value="', $post->ID, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>';
                }?>            
                <?php
                echo '</select>';                
                ?>                      
            </p>       
        <?php     
        } 

    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_pglr_user_pages' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_pglr_user_pages' );

    function save_pglr_user_pages( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    //save dropdown

    update_usermeta( $user_id, **$user_custom_post,** $_POST['user_custom_page_value'] );
    }
```

The problem may be using variables...

Comment: Don't add more questions or problems as Answers. Edit your question instead to add more info instead.